# Unexpected character '@' for webpack "externals" option

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I've found a lot of stuff about "Unexpected character '@'" happening with webpack, but none of it related specifically to, or helpful with, getting that error for the `externals` webpack option. I've used this before, both with and without @-signs, without any trouble, so I don't know why webpack is getting cranky now.

```js
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    entry: './build.ts',
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: `build.js`
    },
    node: {
      __dirname: false,
      __filename: false,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
      mainFields: ['es2015', 'module', 'main', 'browser']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/i,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: { configFile: 'tsconfig-build.json' },
          exclude: [/\/node_modules\//]
        }
      ]
    },
    externals: ['chalk', '@tubular/util'],
    optimization: {
      minimize: true,
      minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: false,
          output: { max_line_len: 511 }
        }
      })],
    },
  };
};
```

The @ is a necessary part of the package name that I want to exclude, and I've exclude such packages before, so this is both mysterious and annoying.

Anyone have any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with '@vue/composition-api'. Did you filled a bug report or something ?

Comment: No, I haven't filed a bug report. I wasn't sure if it was a bug, or something I'd set up incorrectly. It's beginning to sound like a bug, however. What's weird is I have other projects right now that use the @ without any problem, so I don't know what the difference is well enough to characterize the bug.

Comment: Does your working projects uses the same version of webpack ? Mine uses webpack 5.37.0

Comment: The error does not happend if I add `type: 'umd'` to the `library` node.

Comment: I'm using webpack 5.37.0 both where @ works and where it doesn't. But just like you, where it works I'm using 'umd'.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution, I was also facing the same issue with Vue.js Project `--mode production`. All other modes were working fine.

```js
externals:[
      {
        ["@company/library-name"]:{
          root: "@company/library-name"
        }
      }
    ]
```

This is basically using the object syntax from official [docs](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#combining-syntaxes).

Comment: Since my own work-around solved the problem for me, I have no place left to try your solution, but it looks good if I need this again, so that's worth an up-vote. :)

Comment: just to add on this: using `externals: ['somepkg']` expects a variable called `sompkg` to exist (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#string), so `externals: ['@some/pkg']` will have `@some/pkg` verbatim in the bundled source. Hence no wonder the OP had a syntax error which terser chocked on. For a Node.js target, probably `'@some/pkg': 'commonjs2 @some/pkg'` is more appropriate than `root:`.

Answer (score 2):

`Webpack` [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals) option is dependent on the [externalsType](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externalstype) one. By default, `externalsType` is `var`, this means that you expect this variable to exists in the global scope.

For example, if we import `jQuery` in the browser through a script link:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.slim.min.js" ...></script>
```

There will be a global variable in the `window` object named `jQuery`, so this `Webpack` configuration:

```js
externals: {
  jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

Is stating:

> When you find an import from `jquery` remove it from the bundle and use the `jQuery` global variable in its place.

If you put this configuration without `externalsType`:

```js
externals: ['@tubular/util'],
```

Webpack will try to replace those requires or imports by a global variable named `@tubular/util` in this way:

```js
var t=@tubular/util;
```

And that will throw an error for sure.

On your specific case, `@tubular/util` [imported through a script tag](https://github.com/kshetline/tubular_util#via-script-tag) creates a `tbUtil` global variable, so your configuration should be:

```js
externals: {
    '@tubular/util': 'tbUtil'  
}
```

This error could also appear if someone is trying to compile a `Node` bundle and they want to exclude some packages from the bundle that are already installed. For example, if you use this `externals` configuration without specifying a proper `externalsType`, you will get a similar error.

```js
{
    externals: ['@babel/core']
}
```

In these cases, you should specify a proper `externalsType` depending on your needs ([these are all the options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externalstype)):

```js
{
    externals: ['@babel/core'],
    externalsType: 'commonjs'
}
```

And then, `Webpack` will replace

```js
import { transform } from '@babel/core';
```

into something like:

```js
var b=require("@babel/core");
var t=b.transform;
```

And it will not ship `@babel/core` in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I found *an* answer, but it's certainly not *the* answer I was looking for.

If I use the package `webpack-node-externals`, I can externalize all `node_modules` like this:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

 // ...

    externalsPresets: { node: true },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
```

In this particular case excluding all node externals happens to be just fine, so `webpack-node-externals` solves my immediate problem. But if I wanted to be more selective, and wanted to exclude a package with an @ in the name, I'd still have a mystery on my hands.